# Vuelidate empty object on select validation issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I would like to know how to validate empty object using vuelidate. I tried to give a demonstration on jsfiddle as links follows

```
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
const { required, minLength } = window.validators

new Vue(
    {
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            companies: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'facebook'
                }, 
                {
                    id: 2, 
                    name: 'apple'
                }
            ],
            text: {
                id: null,
                name: null
            }
        },
        validations: {
            text: {
                required
            }
        }
    }
)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5v4faqf/1828/)

Comment: Please include the code you tried and indicate what error you're getting and what line the error is occurring on.

Comment: sorry my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$v.text` is valid because it is a non-empty object. That means it doesn't have 'falsy' value so it meets the requirement. One way to make it work:

```
validations: {
    text: {
        id: {required},
        name: {required},
    },
},
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/4y0np904/)

If you don't want to repeat items object structure, you can write a [custom validator](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-custom-validators).

Answer (score 1):

There is missing information about how to use `withParams` in the documentation of vuelidate page. 
So i have searched on its github page and found this [link](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate/issues/168) .
According to link i came up with that solution

```
import { withParams } from 'vuelidate'

export const checkIfNull = withParams(
  { type: 'required' },
  value => (value.id === null ? false : true)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about validating an object, you just need to define the structure and add any validation rules you require.

Please see the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/74qk22v4n1) I created and take another look at the [Collections](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-validation-groups) docs.

Comment: it seems it is still invalid

Comment: My example will be invalid until the requirements are me - so enter a name and give a value between 18-60 and it will become valid.